# Why is a dynamic created JSF EL value expression not resolved?

Tags: jsf, el, javabeans, dynamic-content

I got a simple setup (and a big issue): a JSP page with en empty panel grid item container and a binding to a bean.

```
<h:panelGrid binding="#{ bean.container }" id="container" />
```

When the getter of the bean will be called, the container is filled with a random number of columns with a command link inside. So far so good. The container is filled up with the right number of elements, and with the use of an ActionListener on the links, I get all click events.

Here comes the tricky part: I want to mark the 'selected' or 'pressed' column via a different style class. With a *static setup*, I would do this with an expression like:

```
<h:column styleClass="#{ bean.selectedColumn eq 'id' ? 'btnSelected' : 'btn' }">
    <!-- command link and some blahblah -->
</h:column>
```

The bean contains a simple getter `getSelectedColumn()` , that returns an id. Straight forward, so this works perfect!

But when I try to do the same *inside the bean*,

```
ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
String expression = "#{ bean.selectedColumn eq 'id' ? 'btnSelected' : 'btn' }";
new ExpressionFactoryImpl().createValueExpression(elContext, expression, String.class);
column.setValueExpression("styleClass", valueExpression);
```

the expression won't ever be resolved. To make myself clear: both the command links, **the columns** and the **value expressions** are generated **inside the bean**. Is that the cause?

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the JSP is compiled the bean wont be called! This is done at runtime cause you want to see live data in the bean. Therefore the (later) generated EL is not visible at compilation. The EL would not be resolved at runtime.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will try something else. Thanks.